# Validating email recipient's domain name with regex in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I would like to check if given recipient has a correct domain in it with regex but whatever I do I always get `false`

Code:

```
from = "Pratha Burna <prathab@mydomain.com>" # or just "<prathab@mydomain.com>"
from.gsub!(/^\s*<\s*(.*)\s*>\s*$/, '\1')
from.downcase!
puts "checking for #{from}" # this should give only email. But whole from is here.

if from !~ /@mydomain.com$/
    puts "false"
else
    puts "true"
end

if from !~ /@another.com$/
    puts "false"
else
    puts "true"
end
```

Sample app: https://ideone.com/arAkKm

What I need to is check if `@mydomain.com` is in `from` variable as an email. Because, user can put `@mydomain.com` to name section and trick the server. What I need to is check inside `<>`

For example this should **fail**:

```
Pratha@mydomain.com <another@gmail.com>
```

Because `@mydomain.com` is not in `<>`

How can I properly clean from and check against domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with the following regular expression:

```
'Pratha@mydomain.com <another@gmail.com>'[/(?<=\@)[^@]*?(?=>\z)/]
#⇒ "gmail.com"
```

The regular expression is:

```
/(?<=\@)[^@]*?(?=>\z)/
```

Anything in between of the `@` and closing last `>`, which does not contain `@`.

---

You can simply compare it against the list of valid domains, or whatever. It grabs the domain and returns it as a string.

---

Another way would be to grab an email address and check if it ends with what you need:

```
from[/(?<=<)[^<>]*?(?=>\z)/]
#⇒ "another@gmail.com"
from[/(?<=<)[^<>]*?(?=>\z)/].end_with?('@gmail.com')
#⇒ true
```

Comment: Awesome! But let me say something. When I check domain name, I also need email (full e-mail) to return. Can you show me another example besides this to fetch email inside `<>`?

Comment: Updated the answer.